Django-Extensions: how to add local variables to shell_plus
I have multiple dictionaries, and I want each key/value pair to be defined in the local scope of a django-extensions shell_plus session.
My current management command looks something like this:
import django
import code

devs = {
    'hot_water': object()
    'air': object()
}
procs = {
    'clean_keg': lambda x: 'do_something'
}

# unnecessary code when using `shell_plus`
model_map = { model.__name__: model for model in django.apps.apps.get_models() }

local = {
    'procs': procs,
    'devs': devs,
    **devs,
    **procs,
    **model_map
}

code.interact(local=local)

Now I find myself wanting to add settings, models, and several other Django objects that are already included with shell_plus, but I can't find a way to add local variables to the shell_plus session.
Brett Thomas's answer shows how to import modules into a shell_plus session, but doesn't show how to add variables from a dict-like object.
How do I add variables to a shell_plus session?

Unpacking a dictionary into local variables is a severe Python antipattern.

@willeM_VanOnsem under normal circumstances I would agree.  In my case, I've have to toggle devices on and off constantly eg. (devs.hot_water.on, devs.drain.on) literally hundreds of times when testing the keg cleaner I'm working on.

@willeM_VanOnsem what would be a pythonic solution to this?  Should I drop the idea of keeping the all devs and procs defined within the shell's scope?

why not add 'my_app.management.commands import procs, devs' to SHELL_PLUS_IMPORTS?

@willeM_VanOnsem because I would have to type devs.some_device.on() every time I needed to toggle it, and most of the time I'm using this tool I have to control 5+ devices.

It's also worth noting that this is a development tool.  In my production code all my devices are called within their namespace, eg. devs.some_device

but if ypou add it to the SHELL_PLUS_IMPORTS, you thus import devs.

You can add the variables from your management command, like:
SHELL_PLUS_IMPORTS = [
    'my_app.management.commands.my_command import procs, devs',
    'from module.submodule2 import function3 as another1',
    'from module.submodule3 import *',
    'import module.submodule4',
]
This will then load the procs and devs from the my_command as variables in the shell.
"Unpacking" a dictionary as local variables can then be done with:
locals().update(**{**devs, **procs})

so variables like hot_water and air are now available.
but, unpacking dictionaries into variables is not a good idea: it can override builtins, like dict, int, etc. Normally if you have arbitrary names, you use a dictionary, or a class variable to encapsulate the logic.
